# Is $M(2,\mathbb Z)$ a Von Neumann regular ring?

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is it true that $M(2,\mathbb Z)$ is a Von Neumann regular ring ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $M_2(\mathbb Z)$?

No. Von Neumann regularity is Morita invariant, and $\mathbb Z$ is not von Neumann regular.

Another, more elementary way to see it: You can't find a matrix satisfying this equation.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
\\=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix}
\\=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: what is Morita invariant ?

Comment: @SaunDev It's a property that all Morita equivalent module categories share. You'll probably learn about it someday. I added a more elementary observation to tide you over.